# Gradle proxy configuration

Tags: java, proxy, active-directory, windows-server-2008, gradle

I need web access from Gradle through a proxy server to use the Gradle/Artifactory integration for Jenkins. To reduce possible causes for issues, I manually add the Artifactory plugin in build.gradle and run it from command line:

```
apply {
    apply from: "http://gradle.artifactoryonline.com/gradle/plugins/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/1.0.1/artifactoryplugin-1.0.1.gradle"
}
```

Following [this](http://gradle.org/releases/0.8/docs/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) description I specified the following in .gradle/gradle.properties in my home directory:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=hostname
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=de\\username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxx
```

With the above proxy configuration (that is otherwise known to work), it fails:

> 11:33:17.699 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://gradle.artifactoryonline.com/gradle/plugins/org/jfrog/buildinfo/build-info-extractor-gradle/1.0.1/artifactoryplugin-1.0.1.gradle

I have two proxy servers to choose from, and one always responds with `407` (*Proxy authentication required*), the other with `502` (*Bad gateway*), so obviously, the proxyHost and proxyPort options are used.

As the user name (based on an Active Directory user) contains a backslash, I tried both `\\` and `\`, but neither worked. The user specified is different from the user that is logged in to the machine and Active Directory. This user's credentials aren't valid for the proxy, so I need to be able to specify a different user.

Setting the same options in Jenkins' or Artifactory's GUI worked.

Comment: having the same problem, none of the answers here helped (even those following the deprecated/non-deprecated methods). then I realized *https* proxy **MUST** be set: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27686730/1024839

Comment: You should look at this url, more complete and updated (with http and https) : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

Comment: @GuillaumeHusta Thanks, but please note this question was posted more than 5 years ago when Gradle 0.8 was the latest release, and the documentation on this was just plain wrong (see my own response to this question).

Comment: I had this problem when using quotes in the proxy, use systemProp.http.proxyHost=x.y.z **not** systemProp.http.proxyHost='x.y.z'

Comment: Deadlink: https://gradle.org/releases/0.8/docs/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using a *very* simple "Request a URL" Java program, I was able to replicate the issue.

`http.proxyUser` and `http.proxyPassword` seem to be non-standard, albeit popular, options, as they're not described in [the Java reference page linked from the Gradle tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html); even though the Gradle manual mentions them.

It seems Java programs that wish to support proxy authentication [need to do this manually](http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2008/05/proxy-authentication-in-java.html) (and I was able to do this using the code on the linked page).

---

I submitted this issue (and a fix) to [the Gradle issue tracker](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1556). Raised issue GRADLE-1556 was resolved in 1.0-milestone-8 (Feb 2012)

Comment: The linked block comes up for me as invitation-only. Is there a public example of this workaround?

Comment: @yock See the attachment of the issue I submitted to Gradle, it's very similar.

Answer (score 257):

Refinement over Daniel's response:

**HTTP Only Proxy configuration**

> `gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost"`

**HTTPS Only Proxy configuration**

> `gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3129 "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost"`

**Both HTTP and HTTPS Proxy configuration**

> `gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3129 "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost"`

**Proxy configuration with user and password**

> `gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -  Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3129 -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=pass  -Dhttp.proxyUser=user -Dhttp.proxyPassword=pass -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=host1.com|host2.com`

worked for me (with `gradle.properties` in either homedir or project dir, build was still failing). Thanks for pointing the issue at gradle that gave this workaround. See reference doc at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

**Update**
You can also put these properties into `gradle-wrapper.properties` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50492027/474034).

Comment: helped me too when using cntlm

Comment: how do u remove proxy?

Comment: also -Dhttps.proxyUser=user -Dhttps.proxyPassword=pass

Comment: in which file we add this settings do we have any file like gradlew.properties? or it goes with gradle.properties file?

Comment: If you put the properties into `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` make sure you prefix the properties with `systemProp`, like for example `systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1`

Comment: @akirti: There is `~/.gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` which is read by gradlew. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50492027/474034

Comment: I tried this and didn't work for me. I had to set the options (`-Dhttp.proxyHost` and the likes) as `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable in order to make it work.

Comment: The most important info is ALWAYS missing - like here. These settings -D... need to be the FIRST and before the tasks to execute on the gradlew command! This is why some people (like me) struggle to make this work! With JAVA_OPTS and _JAVA_OPTIONS you don't have this problem... Please MENTION how important the order is!

Answer (score 105):

This is my gradle.properties, please note those HTTPS portion

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
```

Answer (score 69):

In my `build.gradle` I have the following task, which uses the usual linux proxy settings, `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`, from the shell env:

```
task setHttpProxyFromEnv {
    def map = ['HTTP_PROXY': 'http', 'HTTPS_PROXY': 'https']
    for (e in System.getenv()) {
        def key = e.key.toUpperCase()
        if (key in map) {
            def base = map[key]
            def url = e.value.toURL()
            println " - systemProp.${base}.proxy=${url.host}:${url.port}"
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyHost", url.host.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyPort", url.port.toString())
        }
    }
}

build.dependsOn setHttpProxyFromEnv
```

Comment: It's fun! It is your root's build.gradle or app's build.gradle?

Comment: Works on Windows 7 as well! This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Thanks! the above worked for configuration that doesn't need a proxy password. I have modified it to work with or w/o proxy password see below

Comment: if (key in map.keySet()) {

Comment: This should be a default (if it added the NO_PROXY env variable as well)

Comment: Add it to `~/.gradle/init.d/` as a gradle init script. This way, it will initialize all your gradle builds based on your env variables without having to copy the snippet from project to project.

Answer (score 34):

For me, works adding this configuration in the gradle.properties file of the project, where the build.gradle file is:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxyURL
systemProp.http.proxyPort=proxyPort
systemProp.http.proxyUser=USER
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxyUrl 
systemProp.https.proxyPort=proxyPort
systemProp.https.proxyUser=USER
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
```

Where : 
proxyUrl is the url of the proxy server (http://.....)

proxyPort is the port (usually 8080)

USER is my domain user

PASSWORD, my password

In this case, the proxy for http and https is the same

Answer (score 33):

Check out at 
    c:\Users\your username\.gradle\gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<proxy host>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<proxy port>
systemProp.http.proxyUser=<proxy user>
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=<proxy password>
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=<csv of exceptions>
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<proxy host>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<proxy port>
systemProp.https.proxyUser=<proxy user>
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=<proxy password>
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=<csv of exceptions seperated by | >
```

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Where do you see a link in that answer?

Comment: Basically a link to the local machine and a file dump. Please describe the answer in more detail.

Comment: superrrrrr tnx, u may don't realize how useful ur post was for me but still big thanks

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan How can we pass proxyUser and password by argument ? i dont want to user globle gradle.propaerties file.

Comment: @Nullpointer did u try to use the proxy setting inside the gradle of your project?

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan yes, If I add all above variable on the gradle.properties then I can download gradle-wrapper pkgs from artifactory but those variable are not safe to keep in the server or project. So I have to pass variable for download the gradle-wrapper.

Answer (score 24):

Try the following:

`gradle -Dhttp.proxyHost=yourProxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=yourPort -Dhttp.proxyUser=usernameProxy -Dhttp.proxyPassword=yourPassoword`

Comment: Consider when this question was asked. The issue I link to in my answer was marked resolved towards Gradle 1.0-milestone-8…

Comment: @Daniel this question was first thing that popped up, when I searched for "gradle proxy", I skimmed the answers and that one was the clearest one for my need...

Answer (score 13):

Create a file called `gradle.properties` inside the project folder where the `build.gradle` file is present. Add the following entry

```
     systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy_url
     systemProp.http.proxyPort=proxy_port
     systemProp.http.proxyUser=USER
     systemProp.http.proxyPassword=PWD
     systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy_url 
     systemProp.https.proxyPort=proxy_port
     systemProp.https.proxyUser=USER
     systemProp.https.proxyPassword=PWD
```

If you are using DNS for proxy then add it like `systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.proxysite.com`

For IP just specify the IP with out `http://` or `https://`

 Check [gradle official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) for more details and setting up proxy at global level

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways for using Gradle behind a proxy :

#### Add arguments in command line

(From Guillaume Berche's post)

Add these arguments in your gradle command :

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=your_proxy_http_host -Dhttp.proxyPort=your_proxy_http_port
```

or these arguments if you are using https :

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=your_proxy_https_host -Dhttps.proxyPort=your_proxy_https_port
```

---

#### Add lines in gradle configuration file

in `gradle.properties`
add the following lines :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=your_proxy_http_host
systemProp.http.proxyPort=your_proxy_http_port
systemProp.https.proxyHost=your_proxy_https_host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=your_proxy_https_port
```

(for `gradle.properties` file location, please refer to official documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

---

**EDIT :** as said by @Joost :
A small but important detail that I initially overlooked: notice **that the actual host name does NOT contain** `http://` protocol part of the URL...

Comment: A small but important detail that I initially overlooked: notice that the actual host name does NOT contain `http://` protocol part of the URL...

Answer (score 5):

Based on SourceSimian's response; this worked on Windows domain user accounts. Note that the *Username* **does not** have domain included,

```
task setHttpProxyFromEnv {
    def map = ['HTTP_PROXY': 'http', 'HTTPS_PROXY': 'https']
    for (e in System.getenv()) {
        def key = e.key.toUpperCase()
        if (key in map) {
            def base = map[key]
            def url = e.value.toURL()
            println " - systemProp.${base}.proxy=${url.host}:${url.port}"
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyHost", url.host.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyPort", url.port.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyUser", "Username")
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyPassword", "Password")
        }
    }
}
build.dependsOn setHttpProxyFromEnv
```

Comment: Thanks! There is an update on how to get proxy username and passwords dynamically below

Answer (score 4):

Edit your `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file, then add the following:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-DsocksProxyHost\=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort\=1080 -DhttpProxyHost\=127.0.0.1 -DhttpProxyPort\=1081 -DhttpsProxyHost\=127.0.0.1 -DhttpsProxyPort\=1081
```

- `DsocksProxyHost` is the socks5 proxy host
- `DhttpProxyHost` is the http proxy host
- `DhttpsProxyHost` is the https proxy host

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In case my I try to set up proxy from android studio Appearance & Behaviour => System Settings => HTTP Proxy. But the proxy did not worked out so I click no proxy.

> Checking **NO PROXY** will not remove the proxy setting from the
>   gradle.properties(Global). You need to manually remove it.

So I remove all the properties starting with **systemProp** for example - **systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.local, localhost**

Comment: I've been ripping my hair out for an hour, apparently on Mac, these properties were auto-added to my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

An update to [@sourcesimian 's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1418332/sourcesimian) and [@kunal-b's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3761339/kunal-b) answer which dynamically sets the username and password if configured in the system properties.

The following sets the username and password if provided or just adds the host and port if no username and password is set.

```
task setHttpProxyFromEnv {
    def map = ['HTTP_PROXY': 'http', 'HTTPS_PROXY': 'https']
    for (e in System.getenv()) {
        def key = e.key.toUpperCase()
        if (key in map) {
            def base = map[key]
            //Get proxyHost,port, username, and password from http system properties 
            // in the format http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport
            def (val1,val2) = e.value.tokenize( '@' )
            def (val3,val4) = val1.tokenize( '//' )
            def(userName, password) = val4.tokenize(':')
            def url = e.value.toURL()
            //println " - systemProp.${base}.proxy=${url.host}:${url.port}"
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyHost", url.host.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyPort", url.port.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyUser", userName.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyPassword", password.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the kotlin .kts setting files the properties should be defined like this:

```
extra["systemProp.http.proxyHost"]="127.0.0.1"
extra["systemProp.http.proxyPort"]="12345"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this issue with HTTP error 407 happened to selected packages only then the problem is not in the proxy setting and internet connection. You even may expose your PC to the internet through NAT and still will face this problem. Typically at the same time you can download desired packages in browser.
The only solution I find: delete the .gradle folder in your profile (not in the project). After that sync the project, it will take a long time but restore everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flutter, add the following line in `android/gradle.properties`

```
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.local, localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue after I installed an older version of SDK and set `JAVA_HOME` in `.zshrc`. None of the solutions above helped me out, however, restarting my computer (Mac) finally let the error disappear.