# Gradlew behind a proxy

Tags: gradle, gaelyk

I have a sample from Gaelyk (called Bloogie) and it is using gradlew.

I am behind a proxy.

I've read gradle docs and found this:

gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
```

But I have no clue how to put this info into the wrapper gradlew. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle proxy configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration)

Comment: I had this problem when using quotes in the proxy, use systemProp.http.proxyHost=x.y.z **not** systemProp.http.proxyHost='x.y.z'

Answer (score 78, accepted):

All you have to do is to create a file called `gradle.properties` (with the properties you mentioned above) and place it under your gradle user home directory (which defaults to `USER_HOME/.gradle`) OR in your project directory.

Gradle (the wrapper too!!!) automatically picks up `gradle.properties` files if found in the user home directory or project directories.

For more info, read the [Gradle user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html), especially at section 12.3: [Accessing the web via a proxy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy)

Comment: Thanks i read that and did but there is a problem with Gradlew http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1679

Answer (score 48):

If you need **https access** behind a proxy, please consider defining also the same set of properties for *systemProp.https*.

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

See [Can't build Android app using crashlytics behind VPN and proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073440/cant-build-android-app-using-crashlytics-behind-vpn-and-proxy) for more information.

Answer (score 24):

Add the below in your `gradle.properties` file and in your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file if you are downloading the wrapper over a proxy

If you want to set these properties globally then add it in `USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties file`

```
## Proxy setup
systemProp.proxySet=true
systemProp.http.keepAlive=true
systemProp.http.proxyHost=host
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=local.net|some.host.com

systemProp.https.keepAlive=true
systemProp.https.proxyHost=host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=local.net|some.host.com
## end of proxy setup
```

Answer (score 22):

Use this in prompt line:

```
gradle -Dhttp.proxyHost=***  -Dhttp.proxyPort=*** -Dhttp.proxyUser=**** -Dhttp.proxyPassword=****
```

Works here!

Comment: For proxies that require HTTPS, add `-Dhttps.proxyHost=***` and `-Dhttps.proxyPort=***`. Making it: 
    gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=***  -Dhttp.proxyPort=*** -Dhttps.proxyHost=***  -Dhttps.proxyPort=*** -Dhttp.proxyUser=**** -Dhttp.proxyPassword=****

Comment: Works also when using `gradlew` instead of `gradle` directly

Answer (score 9):

I could not get the proxy property to work until I set the https proxy:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

However I had to use the http property for user name and password:

```
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
```

Answer (score 6):

This problem with the Gradle Wrapper has been fixed with Gradle 1.0-milestone-8. Give it a shot.

Comment: You should go for 1.0-milestone-8a as there was a critical bug in 1.0-milestone-8.

Answer (score 5):

after of [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u111-relnotes-3124969.html) JDK update, I couldn't use gradlew behind a proxy again.
and finally I found a JDK has disabled Basic authentication for HTTPS tunneling by default. 
so I have to add this property for gradle.properties in addition to proxy settings

```
systemProp.jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
```

I hope it would be helpful for someone who struggle same problem

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem and first thing I did was to create gradle.properties. I had not such as file so I should create it with following content:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=domainname|localhost
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=domainname|localhost
```

When I added them gradlew command works properly behind corporate proxy. I hope that it can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

To add more nuances, for my case, when I have **multiple** gradle.properties files in both USER_HOME/.gradle and the project root, I encountered the authenticationrequired 407 error, with the bellow log:

**`CONNECT refused by proxy: HTTP/1.1 407 authenticationrequired`**

This caused my `systemProp.https.proxyPassword` and `systemProp.http.proxyPassword`**blank** in the gradle.properties file under USER_HOME/.gradle, while the gradle.properties file under the project root remained password info.

Not sure the exact reason, But when I remove one gradle.properties in the project root and keep the file in the  USER_HOME/.gradle, my case is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I was found that reading of properties from gradle.properties can be incorrect. In case line contains trail white space, gradle cannot find proxy. check your proxy file and cut whitespace at the end of line. Can be help

Answer (score 1):

This was not working for me at first.
In my case, I had created what I thought was a USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties file but ended up with a gradle.properties.txt file.

From the terminal window an ls command will show the full file names in the .gradle folder.

Then mv gradle.properties.txt gradle.properties

Answer (score 0):

I have the same proxy issue while working with Cordova project.

To fix the issue, I have created a new `gradle.properties` file under the `android` folder of my Cordova project (`hello/platforms/android`), and added the code from your question

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.yourproxysite.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=yourusername
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
```

Comment: That's the content of the question.

Comment: The content of the question is where to create the gradle.properties file and I have given my clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Setting SSl proxy worked for me.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.yourproxysite.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.yourproxysite.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 0):

> An excerpted answer from the linked thread below. It shows how to do
>   this more programtically. Hope it helps

```
task setHttpProxyFromEnv {
    def map = ['HTTP_PROXY': 'http', 'HTTPS_PROXY': 'https']
    for (e in System.getenv()) {
        def key = e.key.toUpperCase()
        if (key in map) {
            def base = map[key]
            //Get proxyHost,port, username, and password from http system properties 
            // in the format http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport
            def (val1,val2) = e.value.tokenize( '@' )
            def (val3,val4) = val1.tokenize( '//' )
            def(userName, password) = val4.tokenize(':')
            def url = e.value.toURL()
            //println " - systemProp.${base}.proxy=${url.host}:${url.port}"
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyHost", url.host.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyPort", url.port.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyUser", userName.toString())
            System.setProperty("${base}.proxyPassword", password.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

[See this thread for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration/49498041#49498041)

Answer (score 0):

After lots of struggling with this and banging my head against a wall, because *nothing* on my system was using a proxy: it turned out that my ** Android Emulator instance ** itself was secretly/silently setting a proxy for me via Android Emulator > Settings > Proxy and had applied these settings when playing around with it weeks earlier in order to troubleshoot an issue with Expo.

If anyone is having this issue, make sure you check 100% to see if indeed no custom proxy settings are being used via:  `./gradlew installDebug --info --debug --stacktrace` and searching for `proxyHost` in the log output to make sure of this. It may be your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The following applies when your gradle archive is mirrored *behind* the firewall (like mine..):

For some reason, I needed **both** of these lines:

gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.localserver.co
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.localserver.co
```

EVEN though my download line started with `https`, such as below:

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://s.localserver.co/gradle-7.0.1-bin.zip
```

It wasn't working in *ANY* other way... except only it worked *if I used* `export JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localserver.co|etc`.
Even though my environment variable `no_proxy` was already correctly set, it wasn't working without the two values in the above properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
gradlew.bat clean build -Dhttps.proxyHost=pushit-proxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=koacervate -Dhttps.proxyPassword=myShitP@$$w0rd
```

Answer (score -3):

```
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userId
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
```

same with https......