# Cannot run Gradlew: get Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to run gradlew to build some code that had been supplied to me.  The source is the ZIP download from [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-saml) and all I've done is open a command prompt, cd to that folder and run gradlew.bat.

I've had this work on my crash'n'burn machine but I can't get it working on my main dev machine.  The dev machine sits behind a proxy which requires authentication, the other machine doesn't - they're at different locations.

Originally, I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938994/gradlew-behind-a-proxy), to gradle.properties, I added:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=192.168.x.y 
systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
systemProp.http.proxyUser=myuserid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=mypassword
```

and ran it again and got:

```
C:\Users\tso259sa\workspace\spring-security-saml-master>gradlew.bat
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.4-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3052)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3046)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:67)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:49)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:51)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
```

For info, if I try an incorrect password or ID, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
```

so I think that rules out incorrect ID.  Anyone have any ideas what I can try?

Comment: I found this answer useful, I also had the same problem. [Answer to -> UnknownHostException error, building java grpc example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57324396/11618893)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what caused the connection reset but I tried again several times, in case it was transient and, after some time, the response changed to:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned 
HTTP response code: 403
```

Suspecting our security systems, I tried to download the file using a browser and received a message from one of the security boxes saying it had been blocked because it contained a .bat file: a regular occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Look in your build.gradle and gradle.properties and edit 'https://' to 'http://' in all links

Answer (score 1):

I still got this issue today. Different company has different proxy settings. 
after investigate, it worked for me:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
systemProp.https.proxyHost=[server name]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=[port]
systemProp.https.proxyUser=[user name]
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=XXXXX
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts= localhost
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[server name]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=[port]
systemProp.http.proxyUser=[user name]
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=XXXXX
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts= localhost
```