# UnknownHostException error, building java grpc example

Tags: java, gradle, proxy, grpc, unknown-host

I am following [this grpc tutorial](http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/java.html#before-you-begin) and I haven't even been able to make it through the first step. The first step is to git clone the project and then run

```
cd examples
./gradlew installDist
```

I am hit with this stack trace

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

I thought that was a proxy issue, so I took some inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152406/exception-in-thread-main-java-net-unknownhostexception-services-gradle-org) and opened up the file

```
gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

and added the lines

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<my proxy>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<my port>
```

I also replaced distributionUrl line with this

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip
```

That is, I switched https --> http.

After all of this, I am still getting the same stack trace.

Anybody have advice?

EDIT : I added a

```
gradle.properties
```

file in the home directory, and added the fields

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost
systemProd.http.proxyPort
```

and

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost
systemProp.https.proxyPort
```

but I still got the same error as before. HOWEVER, the build script appeared to stall on this line

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip
```

For about 10 seconds or so, before failing. So... progress?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and finally found this solution after 2 hours...

Go to the file **gradlew.bat** in your project and change **DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS** variable as below:

```
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=YOUR_HOST -Dhttp.proxyPort=PORT -Dhttp.proxyUser=USERNAME -Dhttp.proxyPassword=PASSWORD -Dhttps.proxyHost=YOUR_HOST -Dhttps.proxyPort=PORT -Dhttps.proxyUser=USERNAME -Dhttps.proxyPassword=PASSWORD
```

then run `gradlew clean build`.

Comment: Your comment helped me out, also after searching for almost two hours! Thank you very much legend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is an optimal solution, but what eventually worked for me was to replace

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-bin.zip
```

with

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip
```

Essentially upgrading the version of gradle I am grabbing.

I also added a global

```
~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

In my home directory with all the proxy info I had previously declared. My attempt to build after doing this was unsuccessful, but I can't say for sure if doing this had zero impact.