# cordova build android command error

Tags: android, cordova, build, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

> **while building cordova project i get the follwing error on running command cordova build android?**
>   please help with the follwoing code

```
 C:\Users\gaurav-s\hello>cordova build android
```

ANDROID_HOME=D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        :android:unspecified
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradl
  >   e/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentic
  >   ation Required
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.001 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\gaurav-s\hello\p
latforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\gaurav-s\hello\platforms\andr
oid\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Comment: are you under a proxy? If you are, check this out to set your proxy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219065/gradle-cant-connect-to-maven-repo-through-corporate-proxy-need-to-configure-t

Comment: after i changed the setting i am getting the following error "Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradl
e/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentic
ation Required"

Comment: can you edit your question and copy paste the next entire error that comes out? Maybe this is also something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration

Comment: updated the new error.

Comment: This happened to me before. It might be a certification problem. Ignore the part about eclipse, but just import the certificate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887829/peer-not-authenticated-while-importing-gradle-project-in-eclipse

Comment: still the error remains same. :(

Answer (score 0):

Build tools have been moved from maven to jcenter. Go to your `gradle settings` file. Change

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

to

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

It is better to update your gradle to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

- This is because of gradle error Download the file
- **http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip**
- and extract it in any of directory and set the path by open cmd and
  enter
- **setx path (extracted direstory)/bin**
- after reopen cmd and check whether the gradle is works or not by give
- **gradle -v**
- it shows the gradle version output .
- Now the error is fixed run
- **ionic build android**