# Unable To Build Cordova Project for Android in Eclipse and as well in CLI

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, maven

I am New to **Hybrid Mobile Application**. While I try to Build my First Project am Getting the Below Error.

Please help me out of this.

[image: Shared the Screenshot Below]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By referring Cordova site I have installed Node.js ans Gradle, Also Configured the Path Variables. I was able to create a project and Add a Platform but when I try to Build the Project I am getting the above mentioned Error.

Comment: Try using `cordova build -d` for _verbose_ mode. It might give you some hints on the problem.

Comment: Have used cordova build -d. But I did not get any Hints.. Anyway thanks for the suggestion @Guillem Vicens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error I guess you are behind a proxy firewall connection which is blocking the downloads from maven repository. You may have to configure Gradle to use a proxy server.

This is done by creating a **gradle.properties** file with the following properties set:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost  

systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Place the gradle.properties file in your Gradle home folder. 
For Windows, it is %USERPROFILE%.gradle (Ex: **C:\Users\username.gradle**).

Check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938994/gradlew-behind-a-proxy) which should be helpful.