# Build errors in Spring.io REST tutorial

Tags: java, spring, rest, gradle

I am trying to do the Spring REST Tutorial, and I am getting these build errors while using gradle build tool thats recommended in the tutorial.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Thanks for the help

```
C:\Users\Desktop\gs-rest-service-master\gs-rest-service-master\initial>
gradlew build
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostExcep
tion: services.gradle.org
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java
:178)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLC
onnection.java:996)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConne
ction.java:932)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection
.java:850)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1300)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle proxy configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by setting my proxy settings.

Created a file called gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=my.prox.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=12
```

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Answer (score 2):

The error message is self-explanatory. Your DNS isn't working properly. `services.gradle.org` resolves correctly on my machine.

Comment: Does it have to get online in order to build a local project?

Comment: Yeah figured out how to set the proxy settings and that solved it.

Comment: @am6sigma It has to get online to download dependencies. I'm not sure what the Gradle syntax is, but Maven has a goal `dependency:go-offline` that makes sure to download everything it'll need.