# Gradle build is failing [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.]

Tags: java, eclipse, build.gradle

I am trying for so many days to resolve this exception , followed many blogs and couldn't find  solution. when I run a bundle.gradle by giving jettyRun as command [image]

```
I am getting an exception 



    **FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
        > Could not resolve javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5.
          Required by:
              :1-SimpleServlet:unspecified
           > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.pom'.
              > Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
        > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2.
          Required by:
              :1-SimpleServlet:unspecified
           > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.pom'.
              > Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused**
```

Answer (score 19):

The real error is this:

```
Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
```

Gradle needs to download the dependencies listed in the error message to be able to compile the project.

You're probably behind a firewall or your Internet connection isn't working. You need to make sure Gradle can access `http://repo1.maven.org`.

Note: Maven Central (http://repo1.maven.org) can be accessed with a browser. If you see the message "Browsing for this directory has been disabled" that means your browser could connect to the server (the error is a special message my Maven Central, not a standard HTTP error message).

If you see this but Maven or Gradle fail, then you need to check your browser's/OS's proxy settings and configure your tool accordingly.

Related:

- [How do I use Maven through a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251192/how-do-i-use-maven-through-a-proxy)
- [Gradle proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration)

Comment: the dependencies are listed in my project , but when I open http://repo1.maven.org there was a message "Browsing for this directory has been disabled."..so how can I fix this then?

Comment: @PrajyodKumar: Read the rest of the text.

Comment: To fix the problem with Gradle, you need to configure it to use the same proxy settings as your web browser.

Comment: I have same problem. I can access google.com normally but can not access repo1.maven.org.
Not meaning can not access. The message is 
"Browsing for this directory has been disabled...."

Comment: @KouTokyo: Maven Central doesn't allow to access this URL with a browser. But when you get the error page, that means your browser could connect to Maven Central - so the firewall is OK.

Answer (score 9):

Using --refresh-dependencies switch with gradle, helped me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was resolved when I changed my gradle version from 4.6 to 4.7.

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron Digulla said I have firewall problem.

I was having problem with **GSON dependency**, (hope it will solve other dependecy problems also) and this answer solved the problem. Stack Overflow [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26671662/2032561)

@Kangars post :
This is what i have in my **gradle.build** for build script and allprojects

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of slow internet connection or you haven't configure proxy settings correctly. Gradle needs to download some dependencies , if it cant access the repository it fires this error. All you have to do is check your internet connection and make sure gradle can access the maven repository.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause
`Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused`
indicates that the build is failing as gradle is not able to fetch some dependencies from the repository.

Here is a list of causes and corresponding resolutions you might want to try:

1. Internet connectivity issues - Have a good internet speed and connectivity
2. Firewall (system or third party) - Ensure firewall is not blocking access to the repository
3. Working behind a proxy - [Gradle proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration)
4. Firewall or some random application meddling with proxy application<sup>1</sup> - Kill the process meddling with the proxy application
5. The proxy application causes certificate problems<sup>2</sup> - Import proxy application's certificate

*References:*

1. [Telerik forum's answer on how to fix internet connectivity issue while using Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-causes-my-internet-access-to-stop-working#2Q_DSu6nmE66fQo3ZYUiOw)
2. [Telerik forum's answer on secure connection issue while using Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/forums/your-connection-is-not-private-whenever-i-start-fiddler#Z6f4xKmGN0C-1SizhehzAw)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a working internet connection or haven't configured your proxy/firewall. 
Please check if you can access repo1.maven.org from commandline or a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I used the steps below to fix it.

1. Go to command prompt and set the java opts.

   ```
   SET JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=your_proxy_server_name -Dhttp.proxyPort=your_proxy_port -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1
   ```
2. Then build your Gradle application and all the connection refused errors no longer appear.

   `gradle clean build distZip`

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked after turning on the VPN. Although the build seems to take a long time and seems to stall at 85%, the service is actually building and I'm able to load it

Answer (score -1):

For my case it was a poor connection issue so the IDE couldn't get resources online