# Force Gradle to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: android, http, gradle, proxy, react-native

I am trying to build react-native android app, as a dependecy I see I have gradle, but it fails to load on build.
Error message:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MobileApp'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1.
     Required by:
         :MobileApp:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.1/gradle-1.3.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.3.1/gradle-1.3.1.pom'.
               > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

The issue is clear, I am sitting behind corporate proxy that blocks any HTTPSconnections like these in error.
So my questions are: how to force gradle to use HTTP in loading these files? Where these properties should be put(which of gradle files, i.e. gradle.properties)?

P.S. I already have set these in gradle properties file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost= myHost
systemProp.http.proxyPort= myPort
systemProp.http.proxyUser= myUser
systemProp.http.proxyPassword= myPassword
```

Any links, suggestions or etc. will help a lot.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994163/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath.

Comment: This is the correct answer! Thanks a million, I've googled in wrong way probably, because I didn't come across this link you provided! It saved me some time! Cheers! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Have you upvoted the linked question and answer?

Comment: Yea, I did. I always upvote the Q and the A that helped me. :)

Comment: Great, not all of user do :/

Comment: Yea, I know - little bit sad. Lets hope in near future it will be default behavior of an average stackoverflow user. :)

Answer (score 28):

I had same problem and fixed it.

gradle is forced to get dependencies from jcenter through https proxy.

if you add

```
maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
```

in your repositories instead of `jcenter()`, gradle sees this repository as a simple maven repository with http proxy.

your project `build.gradle` should be like below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was having an issue with HTTPS behind firewall, this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeeeey! After only about 2 hours my gradle build works! Thanks :)

Comment: This no longer works since Jan 2020 as jcenter returns 403 Forbidden on HTTP requests.  See https://jfrog.com/blog/secure-jcenter-with-https/

Comment: @DBPaul Then what is the fix for it. I need a help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ABHIMANGALMS  check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66651640/jcenter-deprecation-impact-on-gradle-and-android

Or try
`maven {url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" allowInsecureProtocol = true}`

Comment: @stefan-dan Thank you very much for your response. 
But still, I'm not able to build the gradle. 
I'm trying to build https://github.com/abhimangalms/pulse-sms-android .  
can you please check. It would be a great help.

Comment: The jcenter() and bintray.com servers will be down after 2022, that's why you get the Forbiden status. It will be much harder then just changing the URL, you have to replace with something from Maven or to remove that 7 dependecies that are not available anymore. For more details check: https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

Answer (score 11):

replace jcenter() with jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"} in build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- run a proxy like freegate
- the root path project in cmd type

  `gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580`

File -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Gradle -> Global Gradle Settings -> Gradle VM Options

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxyAddr
-Dhttp.proxyPort=myProxyPort
-Dhttp.proxyUser=myUsername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=myPasswd 
-Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain=myDomainName
```

Comment: how about adding above Host and port in gradle properties

Comment: Edit answer check again.

Answer (score -1):

Go into the `gradle/wrapper` folder nearby and edit the `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Then add in a the https to the distribution URL and it should work.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
                    ^
```

Verify the file you are trying to grab is actually on the repo:

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

Rerun your command to get the gradle wrapper version.

```
gradle wrapper
gradlew.bat wrapper -gradle-version="1.10"
```

Hope that helps.