# Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/.../kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

When running my app Android Studio is running into a build error. The Error is:

Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I  am unsure what the cause of this is and I haven't found a solution researching on Google. It looks like it's a related to a Kotlin jar but my project uses Java only.

My other apps build fine the issue above is occurring for just one project.

If anyone has any insights as to why this is happening I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Jcenter is only available over https is what I get. Maybe gradle is trying to pull over http which is causing the issue. Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029754/force-gradle-to-use-http-instead-of-https

Comment: And this was indeed the issue. Many, many thanks for providing the solution so quickly.

Answer (score 3):

its probably too late but just replace `jcenter()` in root `build.gradle` with:

```
maven {
    url 'https://jcenter.bintray.com'
    name 'jcenter'
}
```

Comment: But this URL is Forbidden now. Any fix ?

Comment: We need to replace "jcenter" with "mavenCentral". Thank you

Answer (score 3):

in the project level **build.gradle** file add **mavenCentral()** to the both repositories

```
buildscript {
    
    ext {
        ...
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```