# Grails application not starting

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, grails

I have been getting these errors all day long when trying to start my Grails application

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':server'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':server:runtime'.
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.30.1].
> Required by:
> project :server > io.grpc:grpc-core:1.30.1
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.30.1].
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-api.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve net.minidev:json-smart:[1.3.1,2.3].
> Required by:
> project :server > org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.RC1 > com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:4.36
> > Could not resolve net.minidev:json-smart:[1.3.1,2.3].
> > Failed to list versions for net.minidev:json-smart.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.30.0].
> Required by:
> project :server > com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dlp:2.0.0 > io.grpc:grpc-auth:1.30.0
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-api:[1.30.0].
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-api.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:[1.30.0].
> Required by:
> project :server > com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dlp:2.0.0 > io.grpc:grpc-alts:1.30.0
> > Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:[1.30.0].
> > Failed to list versions for io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

CONFIGURE FAILED

Total time: 9.626 secs
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not GET 'http://dl.bintray.com/agorapulse/libs/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/65881803/104891 help? JCenter requires HTTPS, your project is configured to access it via HTTP.

Comment: I just added
maven {
    url 'https://jcenter.bintray.com'
    name 'jcenter'
}

it didn't work still

Comment: When I visit that url (https or http) I do get a 403 forbidden in the browser as well.  According to a banner on bintray.com: "Thanks for supporting Bintray! This service has now been sunset, and to assist with migration to the JFrog Platform, paid accounts can login until July 4th."

Comment: See also https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

Comment: How would you suggest I go about fixing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to resolve a dependency using JCenter which has been retired: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/

You need remove any references to JCenter and replace them with a repository that hosts the dependency your project is trying to resolve.

`io.grpc:grpc-core` is available from Central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-core

So you can use `mavenCentral()` in place of `jcenter()`:

```
repositories {
    // jcenter() <- remove
    mavenCentral()
}
```