# react native run android failing

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I follow all instructions from react native android guide page, however when I create project with **react-cli** and run `react-native run-android` I'am getting some errors:

> ```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>    > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1.
>      Required by:
>          :test:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 >
> ```
>
> com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3
>                :test:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 >
>   com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:repository:25.2.3
>
> > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1.
> >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.pom'.
> >     Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.pom'.
> >     Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out
> >     (Connection timed out)
>
> ```
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2 mins 16.65 secs
> Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
> Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
> set up your Android development environment:
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
> ```

I search a full day to figure out what causing this problem on google but nothing found useful.
Here is some info:

> $ java -version
>
> ```
> openjdk version "1.8.0_131"   
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-2ubuntu1.16.04.3b11)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
> ```
>
> $ android list avd
>
> ```
> Available Android Virtual Devices:
>     Name: Pixel_API_25
>   Device: pixel (Google)
>     Path: /home/danial/.android/avd/Pixel_API_25.avd
>   Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
>           Based on: Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86_64
>     Skin: pixel
>   Sdcard: 100M
> ```
>
> $ echo $PATH
>
> `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/danial/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/danial/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/danial/Android/Sdk/tools/bin`

So all things setup correctly I really don't know where is the problem.

> ```
> **First Answer Error Again:**
>
> [Fatal Error] apache-13.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> [Fatal Error] apache-13.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> [Fatal Error] apache-13.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> [Fatal Error] apache-13.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> [Fatal Error] apache-13.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> [Fatal Error] apache-13.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> [Fatal Error] apache-13.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
> [Fatal Error] apache-13.pom:1:44: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong:
> A problem occurred configuring root project 'test'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>    > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1.
>      Required by:
>          :test:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 >
> ```
>
> com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3
>                :test:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 >
>   com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:repository:25.2.3
>
> > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1.
> >     Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.pom
> >     Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:33.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:33.
> >     Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/33/commons-parent-33.pom
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
> >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
> >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:33.
> >     Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/33/commons-parent-33.pom
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
> >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
> >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.8.1.
> >     Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/commons-compress-1.8.1.pom
> >     Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:33.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:33.
> >     Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/33/commons-parent-33.pom
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
> >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
> >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-parent:33.
> >     Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/33/commons-parent-33.pom
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
> >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
> >     Could not resolve org.apache:apache:13.
> >     Could not parse POM https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
> >     Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: What OS that you use?

Comment: @wlisrausr Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Have you tried this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994163/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath

Comment: YES but nothing changed and I still have error :(

Comment: I test my problem with pure android project with android studio when I run project it will install app on emulator and run it perfectly however I read https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html#RunningOnEmulator page about running android project from command line 
but when I run gradlew installDebug on command line I face same error so the real question is how android studio build project and run it on emulator and I can't do it with command line ?

Comment: can you post your build.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties. In gradle.wrapper.properties check that your distributionUrl is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your project could not get dependencies from jcenter. Try to add repos to your `build.gradle` file.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
}
```

Put code above in the body of `buildscript {...}`.

Comment: I update my question your solution have some errors  too

Answer (score 1):

Try following from your root directory.
Make an assets folder in

```
 /android/app/src/main/

 cd android

 ./gradlew clean

 react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

 react-native run-android
```