# INTELLIJ - PKIX path building failed: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am totally new to Java. I am basically a UI programmer who needs to clone a java gradle project to consume data for UI.

I am trying to open a cloned gradle project to Intellij, but it is throwing me the below error -

**A problem occurred configuring root project ''.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download spring-boot-gradle-plugin.jar (org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE)
>
> Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar'.
>
> Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar'.
>
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

Any help PLEASE!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994163/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath)

Comment: It's likely that your network is monitored by your company and they perform MITM attack on TLS connections. You need to get a certificate they're using to sign their fake certificates and install it into Java key store. I suggest to ask your system administrators to assist you.

Comment: @vbezhenar Alternatively, the OP is using a very old version of Java which might be missing recent root certificates.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's possible, but this website uses DigiCert root certificate from 2006, so it must be truly ancient Java version (: I doubt that it would be able to run Gradle at all.