# "Unable to load Maven meta-data" error from ForgeGradle on Mac OSX?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, minecraft-forge

I am attempting to set up Eclipse and Minecraft Forge with Gradle on Mac OS X so I can try my hand at modding. Whenever I run either of the following commands, Gradle returns the same error:

```
./gradlew genEclipseRuns
./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854-mdk'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:3.+.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Failed to list versions for net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
```

I've found a number of issues on the web that seem similar to this, namely [this one](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Gradle-fetching-library-from-oss-sontatype-org-throws-403/m-p/50458#M7842), but I don't really understand the answer. How can I get this to work? Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Some details that might be relevant:

- I'm running java 1.8.0_65.
- The Forge version is "forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2854-mdk", which is the recommended mdk for MC 1.12.2.
- I'm using Gradle 6.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help! I seem to have found the problem.

For others who are wondering, changing the maven url from https to http in the repositories of forge's build.gradle solved the error I posted above. However, I kept running into similar errors that seemed to be a result of forge no longer supporting 1.12.2. I deleted the old files and started over with 1.15.2, and now everything runs without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this may be a duplicate of something like:

[Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994163/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath)

essentially : "could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ' classpath'. gradle" in your favourite search engine.

Invalidate your caches and restart intelliJ. If this doesn't fix it, the other solution is to re-prioritise the maven repository you use `jcenter()` either before or after `mavenCentral()`