# Facing this gradle build exception and problems

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Tried every possible way and searched all the internet but it does not solve. this problem occurred suddenly on my multi-module project.

I am using android studio and Kotlin as programming languages. so far I did every solution such as cleaning the project, removing the catch, and also reinstalling the SDK and android studio. but nothing worked.

The problem occurred after I was solving an exception which related to the circular dependencies where I was navigating from one module to another I used implementation ... () for it. but after I found a solution for that removed some of the dependencies and now its showing this message. I added against the required implementation but still nothing worked.

Using Gradle 7.2
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

[image]

these are a few exceptions all are similar:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.1.
```

I will really appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: Hi, please update your question, following [the guidelines here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What you have tried and what hasn't worked? [How can w reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? What versions and platform are you using?

Comment: Hi aSemy I updated some information please check it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994163/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath)

Comment: Hi, did you get solution to this

Comment: Yes in my case let me post

Comment: did the answer helped you? @RichardKamere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I have this dependency in my app-level Gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:2.0.0'
```

and the solution is to either comment this or remove this, the Gradle will sync.