# gradlew bundleRelease Could not determine artifacts for com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0: Skipped due to earlier error

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

Yesterday I did this and everything was fine, for some reason this happens now
anyone has any clue?

[image]

Comment: this solved the issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53055212/16671269
though i'm not sure as to why

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck