# how to show suggestions in searchView like google play?

Tags: java, android, xml

How to make the SearchView which give me suggestions when I write the first character ?
previously I used this library but now it doesn't work.

this is the library
https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView

[image]

Comment: When was the last time it worked?  Was it same machine?  Do you know any changes that were made?  Most likely you are not connecting to the service due to credential changes like going to https (from http) or now using credentials OAUTH2 instead of older credentials.  Both of these type issues are common.

Comment: it worked with me till now in the old projects which have build.gradle (project) level different from the newest projects

Comment: when I added searchview in xml layout 

   <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView>
          
I have this error

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Comment: Open config file with text editor and compare differences : https://developer.android.com/studio/build.  Looks like you did that.  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994163/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-classpath

Comment: I don't know what is the config file and text editor as I am beginner, how to open it?

Comment: Looks like config file is build.gradle.  You can use notepad or just display file on console.