# Gradle Error: Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-appcompat

I'm encountering an issue in my Flutter project with Gradle while trying to resolve the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0 dependency`. The error message states:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

I have added the line,

```
  module:
    androidX: true # Add this line.
```

as suggested by [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/androidx-migration)  page, but it didn't resolve the issue.

I hvae tried solutions suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74092554/could-not-resolve-androidx-appcompatappcompat1-5-1-error-with-gradle-in-andr) question, its comments and in the answer. None helped.

please suggest a resolution, thank you for attending this.

Edit: here is my `android\build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is the `android\app\build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.shopx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    //implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

the `gradle.properties` is

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: can you share some more codes like gradle of the project

Comment: The artifact is available without problems. Make sure `google()` repository is in your list of repositories for the app and you internet connection is correctly working: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat/1.3.0

Comment: @ChiragThummar, please see the edit

Comment: @Robert, yes, there are `google()` and `mavenCentral()` in the respositories.

Comment: You may be missing code in ```gradle.properties``` file. Check for this code ```android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true```.

Comment: @ChiragThummar. nope, gradle properties are rightly there..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe updating gradle can help.

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

android/build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

[Update Gradle in Flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920708/update-gradle-in-flutter-project/70885800#70885800)

Comment: here is my gradle-wrapper.properties,

`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip`