# Android Robolectric is not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

## Robolectric ISSUE

I am new to this Robolectric, It is not able to download the file from parent directory

testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2"

This is redirecting to the below location.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-1/android-all-4.4_r1-robolectric-1.pom

The start of this is ok. The below is redirecting to the wrong path, if I am not wrong.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
</parent>
```

because of this we are redirected to the below directory.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/

We don't have "7" sub directory, instead we have 8,9.

Suggest me if anything wrong in my thinking

Thanks in advance. Please help how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Other had reported similar issue when you sit behind a proxy. This should be fixed when you configure your maven proxy settings.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29946704/3619179

Comment: I have added the proxy settings in mine also but no change. Please help in me how to come out of this issue.

Comment: Do you have any custom repositories defiened in your maven setting.xml? Please add yor error message.