# the ggts cant import the spring source code

Tags: spring

I want to read and learn Spring's source code, but I cant import the gradle project after I download the source cdoe.

Here is the error message

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saqnv.png)
can anybody help me?

Comment: Please add the messages as text, not as an image. The errors suggest no internet connection, but since you can post here, perhaps [you need to set a Gradle proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration)?

Comment: yeah ,the error message really makes me confuse, because I can access every link cant connect in the message... have you ever deployed the spring source code like me? thanks