# Gradle Behind Proxy

Tags: jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jenkins-plugins

I am running gradle (version 3.1) behind a proxy server which does not require authentication. I have set the following in gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=xxxx
systemProp.http.proxyPort=xxx
systemProp.https.proxyHost=xxx
```

But I am getting connection reset error when I run gradle.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project '01_dev'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.xxxxxxxxx.gradle-plugins:1.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.xxxxxxxxx.gradle-plugins:1.1.5.
         > Could not get resource 'https://xxx/artifactory/gradle-plugins-1.1.5.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://xxx/artifactory/gradle-plugins-1.1.5.pom'.
               > Connection reset
```

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration ?

Comment: I am facing different error from the above url.

Comment: Check the answer from the  question I likened to. I think you  are not passing the correct properties. The question itself has an incorrect example. The error you get is dependent on the way the network is configured. A reset connection or a timed out one would be the more common ones.