# error with gradle 2.2.1

Tags: android, gradle

I updated Android Studio to 1.4.1 version. gradle sync said needs to version 2.2.1.
I downloaded gradle 2.2.1 and in file-->settings-->gradle set use default gradle wrapper and in 'project location/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties' set distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.

but android studio has errors:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'Scanner'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.
>        Required by:
>            :Scanner:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.1
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.
>   Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.pom
>   Content is not allowed in prolog.

what is problem? and how can solve this?

gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you post your gradle file?

Comment: Are you behind firewall or proxy?

Comment: yes i use vpn in build project . is this problem?

Comment: Make sure gradle has internet access.

Comment: Try to install latest version of AS (2.2), i think that 1.4.1 version is too old, so there is may have some issues.

Comment: Fixed the issue?

Comment: Yes i install last version of Androdi studio (2.3 version) and bug is fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you are behind a proxy, try [Gradle proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration). From the error log you posted it looks like gradle is not able to resolve addresses. Make sure gradle has internet access.

Also you can try the following change in `jcenter()`.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

This many a times fixes the issue.