# How to prevent gradlew from download anything?

Tags: gradle, offline, gradlew

I am trying to run gradlew on offline machine. It starts from message

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

and then fails with exception.

What it wants and how to satisfy it?

Comment: This system is rather designed to work online - how would dependencies be downloaded otherwise?

Comment: @Opal so as I wonder

Answer (score 8):

#### Option 1. If you have possibility go online temporary

Command `gradlew` means you are trying to use Gradle Wrapper. It is a tool for automated downloading of Gradle distribution.

In order to download Gradle Wrapper you have to execute `gradlew` command with a proper network connection at least once.
Make sure you have correct network and [proxy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration).

```
./gradlew build
```

Only after that you can build a project offline. Example:

```
./gradlew build --offline
```

#### Option 2. Download distribution by hand

Or, alternatively, you could download [distribution](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) from official site. Then extract it, add `gradle` to `PATH` variable, and run:

```
gradle build --offline
```

Comment: No, it is trying to access internet nevertheless. Tried command `gradlew test --offline`

Comment: Off course, it depends on a specific build. Sometimes third-party plugins don't honor this parameter. Please provide the error output.

Comment: This question is about auto-downloading the gradle wrapper, not the dependencies of the project.

Comment: @MirceaD. Thanks for the hint. I've fixed it