# How to disable downloading of sources.jar and javadoc.jar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have configured as follows in app/build.gradle, but it not works. Can someone tell me how to disable download of sources and javadoc? The version of AndroidStudio is 4.0, and the grade plugin version is also 4.0.0

```
idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = false

        downloadSources = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent gradlew from download anything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088767/how-to-prevent-gradlew-from-download-anything)

Comment: Sorry, that question is different. before 3.6 version of Android Studio, there is one setting 
 that skip download of sources and javadoc, but after 3.6, that setting has disapper, so I want to know how to disable it. Thanks.

Comment: same issue , android studio download source.jar and javadoc.jar take long of time

Answer (score 0):

Add idea plugin to gradle file like this:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'idea'
}
```