# No cached version of org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.2.7 available for offline mode

Tags: grails, gradle

No cached version of org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:3.2.7 available for offline mode.

I get after i installed IntellijIDEA and created a test Grail project and run the build, it is fairly new no changes done, just empty project and build..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure Gradle is not in [offline mode](https://i.imgur.com/saJByLS.png).

Comment: I did that and i get    Unknown host 'repo.grails.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle

Comment: I did update the gradle-wrapper.properties inside my project

Comment: Check your proxy settings, it looks like Gradle cannot access the default repository.

Comment: i updated graddle*.properties and made sure poxy is enabled in IntellijIDEA , any other places i am missing

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37079513/104891)? Does it build in the command line?

Comment: Yes, i ran grailsw war and it is built sucessfully

Comment: Try setting the proxy using `-Dhttp.proxyHost=www.somehost.org -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080` [VM options here](https://i.imgur.com/rNPDjE9.png).