# How to prevent gradle from using proxy in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA preference setting **`No proxy`**, let me repeat **`No proxy`**, but sync gradle, I found gradle still took proxy setting, No kidding.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019
Licensed to IntelliJ IDEA Evaluator
Expiration date: August 19, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.5
```

How do I know gradle is using proxy, let's see

```
***VERT LONG LONG STACK BACKTRACE***
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:1087 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    ... 190 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    ... 202 more
```

what is 127.0.0.1:1087, that is my local proxy server shadowsocks client agent, I once did the setting in preference for fetching things blocked by our great fire wall, but THIS TIME, I set **`No proxy`** in preference, also I investigated environment variables in case of env dependency things, but there is not such proxy setting in env either, I just want the **`No proxy`** setting in preference should be honored, why is that so hard?

Comment: Do you have set it for Gradle? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151572/104891

Comment: Yes, there is, actually there is gradle.properties in ~/.gradle/ directory, I only noticed there is no such file in project, didn't aware such thing before, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add proxy in the intellij IDEA it automatically adds the proxy in `gradle.properties` but when you remove it from settings it's still there. open `gradle.properties` and remove the proxy.

It should be something like this:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=your_proxy_http_host
systemProp.http.proxyPort=your_proxy_http_port
systemProp.https.proxyHost=your_proxy_https_host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=your_proxy_https_port
```

There are 3 places `gradle.properties` can be placed (if an option is configured in multiple locations the last one wins)

```
gradle.properties in Gradle installation directory.

gradle.properties in project root directory.

gradle.properties in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory. (if you did not set GRADLE_USER_HOME in your environment variable, the default is USER_HOME/.gradle)
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)

Comment: thank you, actually for me, gradle beginner , do not forget there is gradle.properties in ~/.gradle directory, you can mention that point out there, thank you