# Gradle properties proxy not recognized

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-17, gradle-properties

I'm trying to resolve the dependencies from a gradle project, When I opened the project and tried to synchronize gradle I got the following error:

> Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy,
>   please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

Then I realized that I needed to configure the proxy of the company network in gradle, 
I set the proxy in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=someIP
systemProp.http.proxyPort=somePort
systemProp.http.proxyUser=user
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=pswd
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost

systemProp.https.proxyHost=someIP
systemProp.https.proxyPort=somePort
systemProp.https.proxyUser=user
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=pswd
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Then I retried to synchronize the gradle project, but I'm getting the same error:

> Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy,
>   please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.

The `gradle.properties` file is in the following path:

```
project/gradle.properties
```

[image]

I executed `gradlew.bat` from the command line and I got the next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main"
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java: 208)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java: 154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1979)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1086)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java: 1343)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:
    559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java: 185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon nection.java: 1301)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Http sURLConnectionImpl.java: 254)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java: 56)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java: 42)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java: 57)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java: 44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc essManager.java: 65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java: 44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java: 126)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java: 56)
```

Comment: Does the issue occur only in IntelliJ IDEA or in the command line as well if you run `gradlew.bat build` in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried only in Intellij IDEA

Comment: Could you please try from the command line as well?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm pretty new in Gradle, I don't know how to run from the command line, can you give any advice?

Comment: Run `gradlew.bat build` in `cmd.exe` in the project root: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html .

Comment: I would also set the proxy globally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52151572/104891.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I executed the gradle.bat file and I got an exception that I put on the question.

Comment: What `java -version` output do you get in the command line?

Comment: @CrazyCoder ´java version "1.8.0_191"Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)´

Comment: Try a more recent JDK 1.8 build, _191 is too old.