# Android Studio Stuck at Gradle download

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'am Stuck at `Gradle Download Gradle-5.6.4-all.zip` when trying to create a new project in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate Caches and Restart

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have direct access to [Gradle-5.6.4-all.zip](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip).
Check whether you're behind a firewall, proxy,...
If so, read [Gradle Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) and set `Gradle` to their configurations to access the web.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration) link might also help you do that.