# Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/sysdata/maven/androidx/room/room-common/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Tags: android-studio, maven, gradle

I was trying to build and run [Infinity For Reddit 1.0](https://github.com/Docile-Alligator/Infinity-For-Reddit/tree/1.0) in Android Studio and got this error. What do?

This is the top level build file:

```
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url  'https://dl.bintray.com/sysdata/maven' }
        maven { url 'http://repo.pageturner-reader.org' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    roomVersion = '2.2.0-beta01'
    archLifecycleVersion = '2.2.0-alpha03'
}
```

Comment: seems like a internet problem

Comment: Are you running behind a proxy? In this case check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration  This might explain 502 that possibly comes from some kind of your server (an intermediate gateway), rather than from the bintray itself... In any case, try to access this link without gradle and see what happens.

Comment: @MarkBramnik no, that doesn't seem to be the case. i am getting 502 bad gateway without gradle too.

Comment: Got you, https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown Have you tried to run the build like a week ago - it seems that the repo was shut down so you should define some other repo t o work with (I'm more a maven guy, so to me maven central sounds as a good altenative)

Comment: @MarkBramnik thanks for that info. i don't get why build during 'Make Project' works but during 'Run app' it fails.

Comment: well, its hard to tell, maybe during the build it works because you use some kind of local cache, but running the application for some reason requires to actually download something from the remote repository? Maybe you can "backup" the local cache to a different folder (rename or something) and run as if you don't have any cache at all?

Comment: The usage of bintray  will not work because bintray has been closed. Apart from that the usage of the referenced project does not make sense because it is not maintained anymore ???

Comment: @khmarbaise i was trying to figure out how to make a simple reddit client for android. the recent versions are too complicated for my scope, hence resorted to looking at the first release.