# Gradle proxy GitLab CI/CD

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gradlew

I would like to run this [project](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-jvm-spring) in GitLab CI/CD, but when i try to run gradlew, i get this error:
[image]

I guess the problem is the company proxy, which blocks the requests. Therefore i tried to use the exception `SET NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1` in the Gradlew.bat file, but nothing changes. What can i do to make this run?

IMPORTANT
I can't manipulate the Runner in any way, that's not under my control.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5991194/11934850

Comment: Yup, i saw that... but it's not working. Can't even run `gradlew -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=3129 "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost"`

Comment: Have you tried to use a local proxy such as Px? A local proxy can help al lot if you sit behind some NTLM-proxy. Configuring 127.0.0.1 and port 3128 won't help if you have no local proxy running.

Comment: Nope, is Px suitable for CI/CD environment? I would have to install it in my docker image, correct?

Comment: The safest way would be to use something like jfrog artifactory behind the corporate firewall as source for the gradle distribution and handle connection issues to the internet there and not in the ci/cd pipeline.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution however refined is unworkable in my situation. I am trying to find a "workaround" that can solve this issue. I had already faced a similar problem with Mocha for testing. Here a `NO_PROXY` variable made the work.