# Connection timeout error for maven repo in gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am getting below error when Jenkins pipeline is run :

```
  Welcome to Gradle 7.0!
  Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Auth-mapper'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.7.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.7.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.7.7/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.7.7.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.7.7/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.7.7.pom'.
            > Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/146.75.32.215] failed: connect timed out
> Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.1.0.
  Required by:
      project :
   > Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.1.0.
```

my build.gradle file is having these entries :

```
 buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       maven {
       url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
      }
   }
   dependencies {
   classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.7"
   classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.1.0"
   classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:3.0"  
 }
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

When I  run this application in local then its working fine but when I try deploying it to openshift via Jenkins then in the build step its failing due to the above issue.

Comment: Is the OS/Jenkins inside a VPN?

Comment: Yes correct its in VPN..

Comment: So, since it works locally, do you need to set a proxy?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991194/gradle-proxy-configuration

Comment: Some companies do not allow connecting to Maven Central (at least not directly), but instead use a company repository you should use.

Comment: Thanks @User51 I followed that and added proxy configuration it did worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Below configuration in gradle.properties based on above comments worked for me ...

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost
systemProp.https.proxyPort
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts
```

The above properties values needs to be set based on company specific configuration.